# Compiler switch to turn debugging messages on/off?

Tags: haskell, ghc

OK, so here's a simple question. I've written a function `debug :: String -> IO ()`. I'd like to set things up so that when I compile my program one way, this function writes to standard error, and if I compile my program another way, this function becomes no-op. Is there some easy compile-time switch to do that? Or would I have to implement something myself?

Comment: Have you considered using `Debug.Trace`?  [Haskel Debugging](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Haskell/Debugging) gives some decent bit of detail.

Comment: @devnull `trace` won't do what I want - but `traceIO` might...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I don't think involving `trace` is the right approach to solve this problem.

Instead, you could use a preprocessor to disable/enable debug messages. Put the following in a separate file:

```
{-# LANGUAGE CPP #-}
import System.IO

debug :: String -> IO ()
debug message =
#ifdef DEBUG
  hPutStrLn stderr message
#else
  return ()
#endif
```

The `{-# LANGUAGE CPP #-}` line enables the C preprocessor for the current file. You can then compile the file with/without debugging by using `ghc -DDEBUG` or just `ghc`.

Answer (score 9):

You can do this using the CPP preprocessor and `#ifdef`.

1. First, use `#ifdef` to choose between the two versions of the function.

   ```
   {-# LANGUAGE CPP #-}
   module Logging (debug) where

   debug :: String -> IO ()
   #ifdef DEBUG
   debug = putStrLn
   #else
   debug _ = return ()
   #endif
   ```
2. Then, add a flag to your `.cabal` file to control it.

   ```
   ...

   flag debug
     description: Enable debug logging
     default:     False

   executable foo  -- or library
     if flag(debug)
       cpp-options:  -DDEBUG

     ...
   ```
3. Finally, to enable debugging, enable the flag with `-f` when configuring:

   ```
   $ cabal configure -f debug
   ```

Answer (score 2):

To complement the excellent answers given here, I would like to mention this approach, in case people (like me) are using the latest version of `stack` together with `hpack`.

In the `package.yaml` file I added the following:

```
  flags:
    debug: # Or whatever name you want to give to the flag
      description: Enable debug
       manual: True
       default: False

   when:
     - condition: flag(debug)
       cpp-options:  -DDEBUG
```

Then I would recommend to use `traceIO` from [`Debug.Trace`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.10.1.0/docs/Debug-Trace.html) in combination with [`NoTrace`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/NoTrace-0.3.0.2), so that `traceIO` will have no effect when the code is compiled without the `debug` flag:

```
{-# LANGUAGE CPP #-}

-- ...

#ifdef DEBUG
import Debug.Trace
#else
import Debug.NoTrace
#endif              

-- ...
someFunc :: IO ()
someFunc = do
    -- ...
    traceIO "Whatever..."
```

When using stack, the `debug` flag can be enabled by using the `--flag` option:

```
stack build --flag "your-package:debug"
```

Or if you're testing your package:

```
stack build --flag "your-package:debug"
```

If `hpack` is not used, then you can configure your cabal file as explained by
[hammar](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16633370/2289983).